# nodejs Buffer toString changed original buffer

Tags: node.js, buffer, encode

in node.js

```
    const buffer = Buffer.from('000000a6', 'hex');
    console.log(buffer); // <Buffer 00 00 00 a6>

    const bufferString = buffer.toString();
    const newBuffer = Buffer.from(bufferString);
    console.log(newBuffer); //  <Buffer 00 00 00 ef bf bd>
```

Why convert buffer to string, then convert the string back to buffer, the new buffer is different from the original one?

I tried toString('hex') toString('binary') or other encode, like ascii, etc. All these encodes changed the original buffer.

buffer.toString(encode) use the default encode utf8, Buffer.from(string, encode) also use the default encode utf8, it still different.

How can I convert buffer to string, and convert it back to buffer exactly as the original buffer?

PS: This question comes from when I want to send request body as a buffer. I just send  to the server, but the server gets .

PPS: The server is not in my control. So I'm not able to use Buffer.from(string, 'hex') to parse request body buffer.toString('hex').

Answer (score 0):

No need to convert into string like  const bufferString = buffer.toString();

const buffer = Buffer.from('000000a6', 'hex');
    console.log(buffer); //

```
const bufferString = buffer; 
const newBuffer = Buffer.from(bufferString);
console.log(newBuffer);
```

Comment: when i send a request, the request.body will automatic convert a buffer to a string using buffer.toString(), I didn't do this manually. And the string will be recieved by the server, but the string has changed

Answer (score 0):

In other words, you're converting a buffer to a string and back to a buffer using the same encoding both times and the buffer isn't the same? Here's a function to test whether an input string will stay the same for a given encoding. This should tell you which encodings are likely to be problematic.

```
var f = (buf, enc) => Buffer.from(buf.toString(enc), enc).every((e,i) => e === buf[i]);
f("hello world", "utf16le"); // ==> returns true
f("hello world", "binary"); // ==> returns true
```

UTF8 is the default encoding if you don't specify one, so the Buffer sequence in your original answer is very likely bad UTF8 or needs to be escaped in some other way to correctly map it to a UTF8 string.

Comment: I don't understand how encoding then decoding can not be a transparent operation with every encoding. We are basically taking bits, grouping them, and giving them character equivalent. And then making the reverse operation. So when are the bits being changed?